# regular expression for longitude and latitude doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, geo

i try to make validation in longitude and latitude but latitude return with much spaces when i remove regular expression it worked well i don't know what's the problem

view model class:

```
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^-?([1]?[1-7][1-9]|[1]?[1-8][0]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.{1}\d{1,6}", ErrorMessage = "Your must provide a correct longitude")]
    public string Long;

    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^-?([1-8]?[1-9]|[1-9]0)\.{1}\d{1,6}", ErrorMessage = "Your must provide a correct latitude")]

    public string Latt;
```

Comment: On a side note: your regexes let through "180.5" and "-90.999".

Comment: @m69 sorry but i can't understand what you mean, is this a problem , can you explain it ?  thanks.

Comment: I mean that the regex doesn't fully guarantee that the numbers are a valid lat/lon pair, so you need an additional check in your program anyway, so you might as well use a simpler regex that accepts any sequence of digits.